# ggplot2 find number of counts in histogram maximum

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a short R script which plots a few histograms using ggplot2. How can I automatically set the ymax limit in the histogram based on the maximum frequency in the histogram (plus 10%) i.e

```
scale_y_continuous(limits= c(0,ymax*1.1)

plot = ggplot(data, aes(myo_activity)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, aes(fill=..count..))
plot + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(30,90)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0,140))
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For example used data `movies` as sample data are not provided.

With function `ggplot_build()` you can get list containing all the elements used for plotting your data. All the data are in list element `data[[1]]`. Column `count` of this element contains values for histogram. You can use maximal value of this column to set limits for your plot.

```
plot = ggplot(movies, aes(rating)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, aes(fill=..count..))
ggplot_build(plot)$data[[1]]
      fill    y count     x     ndensity       ncount      density PANEL group ymin ymax xmin xmax
1  #132B43    0     0  0.75 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000     1     1    0    0  0.5  1.0
2  #142E48  272   272  1.25 0.0323232323 0.0323232323 0.0092535892     1     1    0  272  1.0  1.5
3  #16314B  454   454  1.75 0.0539512775 0.0539512775 0.0154453290     1     1    0  454  1.5  2.0
4  #17344F  668   668  2.25 0.0793820559 0.0793820559 0.0227257263     1     1    0  668  2.0  2.5
5  #1B3A58 1133  1133  2.75 0.1346405229 0.1346405229 0.0385452813     1     1    0 1133  2.5  3.0

plot + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
         limits=c(0,max(ggplot_build(plot)$data[[1]]$count)*1.1))
```

[image]

Comment: ggplot_build(plot)$data[[1]] gives me very different output -      [,1]   
[1,] List,12

Comment: @moadeep Please update your question with sample data, so to be able reproduce your situation. Also this plot was made ggplot2 version 0.9.3

Comment: The above is the output I got from the commands you typed in your answer

Comment: @moadeep What is your version of ggplot2?

Comment: I had an older ggplot2 version. Thanks for your elegant solution

Comment: Note that this method will also work for weighted histograms where the  normal `hist()`-based solutions will not. GGplot weighted histograms use one variable for the x-axis/binning, and another for the counts. For example: qplot(wt, data=mtcars, geom="freqpoly", weight=mpg)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find the 'hist' function to be the most useful for these sorts of calculations.  The 'hist' function is super fast and can provide your frequency counts.  For your case, you could do something like this:

```
max(hist(data$myo_activity, breaks=seq(range_Min, range_Max, by=bin_Width), plot=FALSE)$counts)
```

Where `range_Min` is the bottom of your theoretical range (i.e. 0), and `range_Max` is the upper limit above your theoretically range.  `bin_Width` is the value width of each frequency count.

The equation should give you the max value you need to specify the plot range.  I believe the 'ggplot' function is calling the 'hist' function anyway, so I prefer to call it directly when I'm only wanting the data.