# facet_wrap equal axis per panel

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to make a plot using `facet_wrap` where the axes can vary for each panel but within a panel the `x` and `y` axes should be the same scale.

e.g. see the following plots

```
df <- read.table(text = "
x y g
1 5 a
2 6 a
3 7 a
4 8 a
5 9 b
6 10 b
7 11 b
8 12 b", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,g=g)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ g) # all axes 1-12

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,g=g)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ g, scales = "free")
 # fee axes, y & y axes don't match per panel
```

What i want is for panel a the x and why axes both to be 1-8 and for panel b the x and y axes both to range from 5 - 12.

Is this possible?

Comment: I wonder if you are keen to draw two separate figures and use `grid.arrange()`. That would be one way to go, I think.

Comment: @jazzurro I was thinking about employing `grid.arrange` although it seems a bit frustrating when you have 8-12 panels.

Comment: I see your point. But, I'd be happy to use ncol and nrow in `grid.arrange` rather than thinking about how I can manipulate x and y axis for each figure.

Comment: Yeah i just wrote a apply to do this, I'll just find out how to match the x and y limits for a ggplot then i could use that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046051/setting-individual-axis-limits-with-facet-wrap-and-scales-free-in-ggplot2) answer you could try the following:

```
dummy <- data.frame(x = c(1, 8, 5, 12), y = c(1, 8, 5, 12), g = c("a", "a", "b", "b"))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
 geom_point() +
 facet_wrap(~ g, scales = "free") + 
 geom_blank(data = dummy)
```

[image]

Comment: If you have more panels you just have to adapt the `dummy` data.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is trick the axes for individual `facet_wrap()` plots by adding invisible points to the plots with x and y reversed so that the plotted data is "square", e.g.,

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = df) + 
       geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
       geom_point(mapping = aes(x = y, y = x), alpha = 0) + 
       facet_wrap( ~ g, scales = "free")
print(p)
```

You could also use `geom_blank()`. You don't need dummy data.

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't an option when the question was asked, but these days I would highly recommend [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) for combining plots.