# How to set the yaxis to equal xaxis geom_point with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a fairly simple scatterplot using ggplot.
I am mainly interested in illustrating a correlation between the x and y axis.
Therefore, I would like the limits of the xaxis to equal that of the yaxis.

```
ggplot(VV,aes(x=R1_Zsc,y=R2_Zsc)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth() +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")
```

I tried the variants below but that didn't work either:

```
ggplot(VV, aes(x=R1_Zsc,y=R2_Zsc)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth() +
  xlim=range(c(VV$R1_Zsc,VV$R2_Zsc)) +
  ylim=range(c(VV$R1_Zsc,VV$R2_Zsc)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")
```

I have made a data frame containingt he xlimits and y limits for each variable, and thought I could use this, but I'm not sure how.

```
df_rng <- ddply(VV, .(variable), summarise, min=range(c(R1_Zsc,R2_Zsc))[1],max=range(c(R1_Zsc,R2_Zsc))[2])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, `coord_fixed(ratio=1)` does not seem to work. I want to set the `xlim` and `ylim` to the same values.

Here is the output plot
[image]

The example from the cars dataset produces the following graph:

[image]

Comment: I can't add an answer, but a very simple solution is to add invisible data to the plot with x and y reversed so that the plotted points are always square, e.g., `+ geom_blank(aes(x=R2_Zsc,y=R1_Zsc))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the key is to make your dataset of minimums and maximums by facet group and add `geom_blank` using that dataset.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28764045/2461552) for a simple example.

I found that thinking through how to make the limits dataset the challenging part of this.  I'll use the `mpg` dataset to give an example.

First the facets with axes on different scales:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Now, make the dataset of the limits.  I do this with functions from *dplyr* and *tidyr*.  This involves finding the minimum minimum and maximum maximum of the two axis variables for each facet group.  I do this in two separate columns, and then gather them into one column.  This dataset needs to essentially have identical columns for each axis variable, so I add the duplicate column with the y axis name last.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

facetlims = mpg %>% 
    group_by(class) %>% 
    summarise(min = min(displ, hwy), max = max(displ, hwy)) %>%
    gather(range, displ, -class) %>%
    mutate(hwy = displ, range = NULL)

Source: local data frame [14 x 3]

        class displ   hwy
        (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
1     2seater   5.7   5.7
2     compact   1.8   1.8
3     midsize   1.8   1.8
4     minivan   2.4   2.4
5      pickup   2.7   2.7
6  subcompact   1.6   1.6
7         suv   2.5   2.5
8     2seater  26.0  26.0
9     compact  44.0  44.0
10    midsize  32.0  32.0
11    minivan  24.0  24.0
12     pickup  22.0  22.0
13 subcompact  44.0  44.0
14        suv  27.0  27.0
```

Now just add `geom_blank` with this dataset to the original graphic and the axis limits are the same within each facet.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free") +
    geom_blank(data = facetlims)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.  I accepted this answer as it allows for the scales to be the same in each facet while having scales free.  I just need to digest the dplyr syntax

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but the problem is that you are specifying the limits in the wrong way. You should not specify your limits as `xlim = range(...)`. This produces the following error:

> Error in range(c(mpg$displ, mpg$hwy)) + facet_wrap(~class, scales =
>   "free") :    non-numeric argument to binary operator

The correct way to specify the limits is as `xlim(range(...))`. An example with the `mpg` dataset from the `ggplot2` package:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlim(range(mpg$displ)) + 
  ylim(range(mpg$hwy)) +
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free")
```

which gives:

[image]

If you want to compare the different facets the correct way, you will have to use the same scales for the axes.

An alternative to the above plot could be:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point(size=1) +
  xlim(range(c(mpg$displ, mpg$hwy))) + 
  ylim(range(c(mpg$displ, mpg$hwy))) +
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free")
```

which gives:

[image]

---

For your own dataset, one of the following two options should give you the desired result:

```
ggplot(VV,aes(x=R1_Zsc,y=R2_Zsc)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth() +
  xlim(range(VV$R1_Zsc)) +
  ylim(range(VV$R2_Zsc)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")
```

or:

```
ggplot(VV,aes(x=R1_Zsc,y=R2_Zsc)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth() +
  xlim(range(c(VV$R1_Zsc,VV$R2_Zsc))) +
  ylim(range(c(VV$R1_Zsc,VV$R2_Zsc))) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")
```

If you only want to include the axis-labels on the left facets (y-axis) and the bottom facet (x-axis), just remove `scales="free"`.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn;t exactly what I wanted as I want x=y but different for each facet, the answer with constructing another dataframe and using geom_blank is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

to produce axes of equal sizes you can put `ratio=1` in `coord_fixed` like this example from `?coord_fixed`

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars) + coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

Comment: Using `coord_fixed` only forces a specified ratio between the physical representation of data units on the axes. However, that is overridden by the `scales="free"` argument in `facet_wrap`. See my answer how to solve the problem, without the need for using `coord_fixed` (which can have unintended consequences for the display of the plot when the limits of both axes do not resemble each other very much).