# how to set limits on rounded facet wrap y axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have this plot and I need to round the y axis so what appears is acceptable EXCEPT for the fact that I would like to not just show 1 value on the y axis. I'd like to add the "limit" to the "scale_y_continuous" function so that the limits for each facet plot are unique to the individual facet.

here is the plot only showing 60 and 80 on the y axis

```
dat = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),A=c(80.6, 82,83,60,61,62),A_up =c(81,84,85,62,63,64), A_low =c(79,78,81,59,58,57), group = c("z","z","z","y","y","y"))
ggplot(data=dat , aes(x=as.factor(x), y=A, group = 1)) + #, color =Group, group = Group 
  geom_line()  + geom_point() + # facet_wrap(~COUNTERPARTY_STRATEGY ,ncol=2)
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = A_up ,ymin = A_low), width = .25) +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(  floor(  (min(dat$A_low)-11)  /10)*10 ,
                                   ceiling(  (max(dat$A_up)+11) /10)*10,10 ),
                      labels = seq(  floor(  (min(dat$A_low)-11)  /10)*10 ,
                                   ceiling(  (max(dat$A_up)+11) /10)*10,10 )
                      ) +
    facet_wrap(~group ,ncol=2, scales = "free_y")
```

Now I add the limit in the scale y continuous and it applies the limit globally.

```
dat = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),A=c(80.6, 82,83,60,61,62),A_up =c(81,84,85,62,63,64), A_low =c(79,78,81,59,58,57), group = c("z","z","z","y","y","y"))
ggplot(data=dat , aes(x=as.factor(x), y=A, group = 1)) + #, color =Group, group = Group 
  geom_line()  + geom_point() + # facet_wrap(~COUNTERPARTY_STRATEGY ,ncol=2)
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = A_up ,ymin = A_low), width = .25) +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(  floor(  (min(dat$A_low)-11)  /10)*10 ,
                                   ceiling(  (max(dat$A_up)+11) /10)*10,10 ),
                      labels = seq(  floor(  (min(dat$A_low)-11)  /10)*10 ,
                                   ceiling(  (max(dat$A_up)+11) /10)*10,10 ),
                     # limits =  c( floor(  min(dat$A_low[dat$group =="z"])  /10)*10 ,ceiling(max(dat$A_up[dat$group =="z"])/10)*10 )   
                      #limits =  c( floor(  min(dat$A_low[dat$group =="z"])  /10)*10 ,ceiling(max(dat$A_up[dat$group =="z"])/10)*10 ) 
                      limits =  c( floor(  min(dat$A_low)  /10)*10 ,ceiling(max(dat$A_up)/10)*10 ) 
                      ) +
    facet_wrap(~group ,ncol=2, scales = "free_y")
```

i.e.

`c( floor(  min(dat$A_low)  /10)*10 ,ceiling(max(dat$A_up)/10)*10 )`

is 50 and 90

but I would like the limit to be unique to each facet plot so something like

so the right plot would have limits of

`c( floor(  min(dat$A_low[dat$group =="y"])  /10)*10 ,ceiling(max(dat$A_up[dat$group =="y"])/10)*10 )`

50 and 70

and the left plot would have limit of

`c( floor(  min(dat$A_low[dat$group =="z"])  /10)*10 ,ceiling(max(dat$A_up[dat$group =="z"])/10)*10 )`

70 and 90

how can the limits be adjusted to be specific to the individual facet plots?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046051/setting-individual-axis-limits-with-facet-wrap-and-scales-free-in-ggplot2 already describes a solution, but it uses also `geom_blank`.

Answer (score 9):

```
dat = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),A=c(80.6, 82,83,60,61,62),A_up =c(81,84,85,62,63,64), A_low =c(79,78,81,59,58,57), group = c("z","z","z","y","y","y"))


dat <- data.table(dat)

dat[, y_min := floor(  min(A_low)  /10)*10, by = group]
dat[, y_max := ceiling(max(A_up)/10)*10 , by = group]

ggplot(data=dat , aes(x=as.factor(x), y=A, group = 1)) + #, color =Group, group = Group 
  geom_line()  + geom_point() + # facet_wrap(~COUNTERPARTY_STRATEGY ,ncol=2)
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = A_up ,ymin = A_low), width = .25) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(  floor(  (min(dat$A_low)-11)  /10)*10 ,
                                    ceiling(  (max(dat$A_up)+11) /10)*10,10 ),
                     labels = seq(  floor(  (min(dat$A_low)-11)  /10)*10 ,
                                    ceiling(  (max(dat$A_up)+11) /10)*10,10 )
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~group ,ncol=2, scales = "free_y") + 
geom_blank(aes(y = y_min)) + geom_blank(aes(y = y_max))
```

So here I use data.table `by = group` to create `y_min` and `y_max` for each group. And then use those values in `geom_blank` to extend the plot area.

[image]

Obviously, this is automatically scalable to any number of groups/facets.

Comment: good anwer. To OP, jm2c, `free_y` will provide bad visual information here if you would compare these two lines. The effect in Z is simply larger than Y but this is not immediately visible. Watch out

Answer (score 3):

One option is to make each of the facets separately, and then stitch them back together. This has the added benefit that you can use something other than 10 for your break sequencing (e.g., if one of your groups spans from 100 to 1000, you could use 200 instead with a little tinkering).

First, I am creating a function to calculate the breaks. (This is the function that you would modify if you want different scales for different ranges.)

```
myBreaks <- function(x){
  seq(floor( (min(x) )  /10)*10 ,
      ceiling( (max(x) ) /10)*10,
      10 )
}
```

Then, use `lapply` to make a plot from the subset of your data for each group:

```
sepPlots <- lapply(levels(dat$group), function(thisGroup){

  ggplot(data= dat[dat$group == thisGroup, ],
         aes(x=as.factor(x), y=A, group = 1)) +
    geom_line()  + geom_point() + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = A_up ,ymin = A_low), width = .25) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = myBreaks,
                       limits = range(myBreaks(dat[dat$group == thisGroup, c("A_up", "A_low")]))
                       ) +
    facet_wrap(~group)
})
```

Note that I still used `facet_wrap` in order to get the `strip`-style title above the plot, though you could just use `ggtitle` instead if you like that styling better.

Then, use `plot_grid` from `cowplot` to stitch everything back together. Do note that if you load `cowplot` it sets it's own default theme. To revert back, use `theme_set(theme_gray())`

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = sepPlots)
```

gives

[image]

`cowplot` is pretty well documented, so you should be able to make adjustments to the plot as needed when you scale up to more groups.

Answer (score -4):

I don't have ggplot installed, but maybe a simple `if () else` could solve your problem. My first attempt would be this:

```
if {
(dat$group =="y") c( floor(  min(dat$A_low[dat$group =="y"])  /10)*10, ceiling(max(dat$A_up[dat$group =="y"])/10)*10 )

else c( floor(  min(dat$A_low[dat$group =="z"])  /10)*10,     ceiling(max(dat$A_up[dat$group =="z"])/10)*10 )
}
```