# Setting individual y axis limits with facet wrap NOT with scales free_y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data

```
library(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(x = c(1,2,1,2), 
                 group = c("a","a","b","b"), 
                 y = c(10,20,1000,2000))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() + 
    facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 30))
```

You can see the B group does not show up because I set the y limit to `0,30`. I want to manually set the individual y limits for each chart. I do NOT want to use `scales = "free_y"` because I need control over the limits in each chart.

Is there a way this can be done?  Can you somehow supply y limits for each chart in a facet wrap?

Comment: you can with `gridExtra` package and individual plots.

Comment: Thats not what I'm looking for

Comment: what's the difference if you want to set the individual y limits for each chart anyway.

Comment: Seems like it's not supported officially: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/187

Comment: It's a lot more work.  What if you have 50,100 plots....

Comment: create a loop that generates your plots and save them as a list.

Comment: that is a last resort.  facet should have this feature

Comment: Feel free to make implement it and send a pull request.

Comment: I had a similar question [How to apply separate coord_cartesian() to “zoom in” into individual panels of a facet_grid()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41536406/3817004). A lot of discussion in comments and chat but unanswered so far.

Comment: I did something [similar](https://github.com/raredd/plotr/blob/master/R/ggplots.R#L1304) but for the x-axis (continuous or categorical), so I'm sure you could the the same for y.. basically add a geom_blank like the answer below. It can be finicky, so it would be nice if this was built in. I avoid ggplot so I haven't revisited this in a while

Answer (score 39):

Unless you want to decrease your plotting area (i.e. not plot some points), you can still have "full" control over your y limits while using `scales = "free_y"`.

You can use the same trick I have given to answer your other question: [how to set limits on rounded facet wrap y axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137060/how-to-set-limits-on-rounded-facet-wrap-y-axis/42590252#42590252)

```
dat <- data.table(dat)

dat[,y_min := y*0.5, by = group]
dat[,y_max:= y*1.5, by = group]

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_blank(aes(y = y_min)) +
  geom_blank(aes(y = y_max))
```

For others reading this question, trick is to explicitly create `y_min` and `y_max` variables for each group. And "plot" them via `geom_blank()`. (Nothing is actually plotted, but each facet's plotting area is adjusted based on `y_min` and `y_max` values for that group).

If for some reasons, you want to manually give min and max (instead of a rule), none is stopping you. But it is tedious:

```
dat[group == "a",y_min := 0]
dat[group == "a",y_max := 30]
dat[group == "b",y_min := 0]
dat[group == "b",y_max := 3000]

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
  geom_blank(aes(y = y_min)) +
  geom_blank(aes(y = y_max))
```

But, as I have mentioned this works if you want to extend your limits, not decrease them.
[image]

Comment: Very clever solution, well explained. But does this also work to "zoom in"?

Comment: Unfortunately no. `geom_blank()` can be used to increase the limits but not to decrease. Can't think of a similar solution for decreasing ("zoom in") right now. Maybe put a condition to remove those 'outliers' for plotting. Thus, if you want to plot y between 2 and 4 only. But your data goes from 1 to 10. Put a condition before plot to remove anything below 2 or above 4.