# Setting independent y axis limits for a faceted variable in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data set:

```
structure(list(move.week = c(NA, 48.399238695958, 236.146623190705, 
NA, 945.029791389357, 290.570264132203, 506.51558841517, 55.6387292109487, 
1051.71558327481, 826.223415851335, 9.89971314284654, 812.361921211564, 
40.0765617306673, 46.4075697564423, 103.491868337776, 44.164028008756, 
98.0674854882126, 28.4460330330234, 0, 259.412139692989, 40.4468636659033, 
16.7571761427655, 12.1723344800463, 301.34211315959, 22.3495825304142, 
700.421193551973, 9.64807366410601, 668.391706142583, 141.556381423833, 
0, NA, 0, NA, 127.660412000685, NA, 21.2605245298569, 87.8291197191404, 
1341.66161912354, 13.270274849292, NA, 202.845399906041, 1.76061395162241, 
29.5284087281041, 30.4840471031898, 91.1777661815095, 170.883152174541, 
0, 1543.27679208739, 230.073204643558, 256.1571165295, 361.223889527833, 
703.86226083476, 156.650204686911, 82.7189167233775, 29.3642007339078, 
30.7958785020237, 81.6641681547624, NA, 781.755687989802, NA, 
NA, 25.6152543629241, 110.367331748619, NA, 78.0570218968284, 
0, 86.4492280284756, NA, 94.5452291266211, 3692.05221011902, 
9.34051794477387, 342.501409143137, 37.5111800749313, 87.1181728191318, 
40.567662090183, 129.172859819661, 9.84083527811312, 33.5282738033928, 
25.4971717785994, 113.29611960839, 56.29973821811, NA, 0.60574412501898, 
96.9393974058932, NA, 4.39929873264574, 10.3227306983852, 190.208123523153, 
8.14262948789631, 38.1004464614978, 20.2628834333788, 76.5649790211705, 
58.1603043926319, 41.2534282319909, 33.2262257142063, 71.144892950572, 
0, 77.8629050196322, 12.4474315334279, 17.7796365069482), Season2 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), Lake3 = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1), y_min = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), y_max = c(1100, 550, 550, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 550, 
550, 1100, 1100, 1100, 550, 1100, 1100, 550, 1100, 550, 1100, 
550, 1100, 550, 550, 1100, 550, 1100, 550, 1100, 1100, 1100, 
550, 1100, 1100, 1100, 550, 1100, 550, 1100, 550, 550, 550, 550, 
1100, 550, 550, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 550, 
1100, 550, 1100, 550, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 550, 1100, 550, 
1100, 1100, 550, 1100, 550, 1100, 550, 550, 1100, 550, 1100, 
550, 1100, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 
550, 1100, 550, 1100, 550, 550, 1100, 550, 1100, 550, 550, 550, 
550)), index = structure(integer(0), "`__Lake`" = integer(0), "`__char`" = integer(0)), row.names = c(515L, 
368L, 327L, 749L, 666L, 577L, 490L, 283L, 314L, 621L, 482L, 679L, 
434L, 839L, 835L, 303L, 851L, 7L, 744L, 156L, 558L, 9L, 396L, 
641L, 112L, 549L, 61L, 466L, 733L, 591L, 439L, 882L, 796L, 807L, 
337L, 516L, 3L, 527L, 215L, 261L, 282L, 83L, 483L, 133L, 340L, 
540L, 849L, 751L, 761L, 501L, 871L, 838L, 391L, 608L, 270L, 610L, 
359L, 711L, 573L, 630L, 581L, 106L, 776L, 29L, 850L, 790L, 336L, 
650L, 424L, 510L, 176L, 125L, 845L, 362L, 820L, 373L, 765L, 435L, 
45L, 431L, 107L, 6L, 403L, 34L, 324L, 131L, 405L, 257L, 794L, 
304L, 517L, 40L, 355L, 646L, 294L, 879L, 298L, 207L, 305L, 196L
), class = "data.frame")
```

And I am trying to build a faceted boxplot with independent y limits for each `Lake3` variable such that the ylim match the independent group limits per the description in this post: [Setting individual y axis limits with facet wrap NOT with scales free_y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588238/setting-individual-y-axis-limits-with-facet-wrap-not-with-scales-free-y)

I am wondering why when I run this in ggplot, the geom_blank layer is not working (see below)?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Season2, y=move.week))+ 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Season2, y= move.week),outlier.color = NA)+
  geom_blank(aes(y = y_min)) +
  geom_blank(aes(y = y_max))+facet_wrap(~Lake3,scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

I am trying to set the ylim for Lake 1 at ylim = c (0,550) and for Lake 2 at ylim = c(0,1100) so if someone can show me how to do this with my data set, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the `ggh4x` package which allows to specify the scale including the limits individually per panel. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131489/12993861 for an example.

Comment: `geom_blank` is useful for expanding an axis beyond the data, but it doesn't work for shrinking an axis. Your `move.week` variable has maximum values of 1051 and 3692 for Lakes 1 and 2, and it is those values that the axis max is based on.

Comment: So is there a way to independently set a coord_cartesian() for Lake 1 and Lake 2?

Answer (score 0):

Though the `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` linked above is *probably* your tidiest way of controlling the facets, one option would be to externally calculate the steps of the boxplot so `ggplot` doesn't put any outliers in (as it doesn't know about them):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  group_by(Season2, Lake3) |> 
  summarise(box = list(boxplot.stats(move.week)$stats)) |> 
  unnest_wider(box, names_sep = "_") |> 
  ggplot(aes(Season2)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = box_1,
                   lower = box_2,
                   middle = box_3,
                   upper = box_4,
                   ymax = box_5),
               stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Lake3,scales = "free_y")
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Season2'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

The reason why the `geom_blank` isn't working to restrict the size of the facets in your code is that `ggplot` is *still* plotting the invisible outliers and expanding the plot above your ymax values to include these super-high values also. Looks like `geom_blank` is useful for making the plot area bigger, but not smaller!