# Define x-range for one part of a facet_wrap in ggplot using cregg package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have seen this [Setting individual axis limits with facet_wrap and scales = "free" in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046051/setting-individual-axis-limits-with-facet-wrap-and-scales-free-in-ggplot2) and that [facet_wrap: How to add y axis to every individual graph when scales="free_x"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400790/facet-wrap-how-to-add-y-axis-to-every-individual-graph-when-scales-free-x) question - however, I am not sure, how I can apply it to my problem.

I use R and the cregg package, see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cregg/vignettes/Introduction.html#Tests_of_Preference_Heterogeneity

This is from the vignette/package explanation:

```
# calculate conditional MMs
mms <- cj(na.omit(immigration), ChosenImmigrant ~ ReasonForApplication + LanguageSkills, id = ~CaseID, estimate = "mm", by = ~ethnosplit)
diff_mms <- cj(na.omit(immigration), ChosenImmigrant ~ ReasonForApplication + LanguageSkills, id = ~CaseID, estimate = "mm_diff", 
    by = ~ethnosplit)
plot(rbind(mms, diff_mms)) + ggplot2::facet_wrap(~BY, ncol = 3L)
```

However, there is a lot of "white space" in the utmost right panel of the figure. Is there a way to set the y-limits of the diff_mms part of the figure? In the example from the vignette, I would like to have the x-limits -0.2 to +0.2 and as they are for the two figures on the left and side.