# Histogram: Combine continuous and discrete values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a set of times that I would like to plot on a histogram.
Toy example:

```
df <- data.frame(time = c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,9,9, ">10"))
```

The problem is that one value is ">10" and refers to the number of times that more than 10 seconds were observed. The other time points are all numbers referring to the actual time. Now, I would like to create a histogram that treats all numbers as numeric and combines them in bins when appropriate, while plotting the counts of the ">10" at the side of the distribution, but not in a separate plot. I have tried to call geom_histogram twice, once with the continuous data and once with the discrete data in a separate column but that gives me the following error:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Happy to hear suggestions!

Comment: Do you need `df %>% count(time) %>% ggplot(aes(x = time, y = n)) + geom_col()`

Comment: But I would like use bins as in a normal histogram. Or do you suggest to merge the bins into one value beforehand and then plotting geom_col like this? Sounds doable, but relatively impractical. Is there another way to still take advantage of geom_histogram?

Comment: You may replace the character value with a numeric value, convert it to numeric.  But, it is not entirely clear to me

Comment: Thanks for the response! Let's say I convert >10 to numeric: Then it would arbitrarily be part of the last bin in the histogram, which I don't want. To say it in other words: I would like to have a histogram with all values 0-10 at binwidth 2. On the same plot, right next to that, I would like to add one barplot that displays the count of values >10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a kind of involved solution, but I believe it best answers your question, which is that you are desiring to place next to typical histogram plot a bar representing the ">10" values (or the values which are non-numeric).  *Critically, you want to ensure that you maintain the "binning" associated with a histogram plot*, which means you are not looking to simply make your scale a discrete scale and represent a histogram with a typical barplot.

### The Data

Since you want to retain histogram features, I'm going to use an example dataset that is a bit more involved than that you gave us.  I'm just going to specify a uniform distribution (n=100) with 20 ">10" values thrown in there.

```
set.seed(123)
df<- data.frame(time=c(runif(100,0,10), rep(">10",20)))
```

As prepared, `df$time` is a character vector, but for a histogram, we need that to be numeric.  We're simply going to force it to be numeric and accept that the ">10" values are going to be coerced to be NAs.  This is fine, since in the end we're just going to count up those NA values and represent them with a bar.  While I'm at it, I'm creating a subset of `df` that will be used for creating the bar representing our NAs (">10") using the `count()` function, which returns a dataframe consisting of one row and column: `df$n = 20` in this case.

```
library(dplyr)
df$time <- as.numeric(df$time)  #force numeric and get NA for everything else
df_na <- count(subset(df, is.na(time)))
```

### The Plot(s)

For the actual plot, you are asking to create a combination of (1) a histogram, and (2) a barplot.  These are not the same plot, but more importantly, they *cannot* share the same axis, since by definition, the histogram needs a continuous axis and "NA" values or ">10" is not a numeric/continuous value.  The solution here is to make two separate plots, then combine them with a bit of magic thanks to `cowplot`.

The histogram is created quite easily.  I'm saving the number of bins for demonstration purposes later.  Here's the basic plot:

```
bin_num <- 12  # using this later

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=time)) + theme_classic() +
  geom_histogram(color='gray25', fill='blue', alpha=0.3, bins=bin_num)
```

[image]

Thanks to the subsetting previously, the barplot for the NA values is easy too:

```
p2 <- ggplot(df_na, aes(x=">10", y=n)) + theme_classic() +
  geom_col(color='gray25', fill='red', alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

Yikes!  That looks horrible, but have patience.

### Stitching them together

You can simply run `plot_grid(p1, p2)` and you get something workable... but it leaves quite a lot to be desired:

[image]

There are problems here.  I'll enumerate them, then show you the final code for how I address them:

1. Need to remove some elements from the NA barplot.  Namely, the y axis entirely and the title for x axis (but it can't be `NULL` or the x axes won't line up properly).  These are `theme()` elements that are easily removed via `ggplot`.
2. The NA barplot is taking up WAY too much room.  Need to cut the width down.  We address this by accessing the `rel_widths=` argument of `plot_grid()`.  Easy peasy.
3. How do we know how to set the y scale upper limit?  This is a bit more involved, since it will depend on the `..count..` stat for `p1` as well as the numer of NA values.  You can [access the maximum count for a histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14584567/9664796) using `ggplot_build()`, which is a part of `ggplot2`.

So, the final code requires the creation of the basic `p1` and `p2` plots, then adds to them in order to fix the limits.  I'm also adding an annotation for number of bins to `p1` so that we can track how well the upper limit setting works.  Here's the code and some example plots where `bin_num` is set at 12 and 5, respectively:

```
# basic plots
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=time)) + theme_classic() +
  geom_histogram(color='gray25', fill='blue', alpha=0.3, bins=bin_num)

p2 <- ggplot(df_na, aes(x=">10", y=n)) + theme_classic() +
  geom_col(color='gray25', fill='red', alpha=0.3) +
  labs(x="") +  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=expansion(add=1))

#set upper y scale limit
max_count <- max(c(max(ggplot_build(p1)$data[[1]]$count), df_na$n))

# fix limits for plots
p1 <- p1 + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max_count), expand=expansion(mult=c(0,0.15))) +
  annotate('text', x=0, y=max_count, label=paste('Bins:', bin_num))  # for demo purposes
p2 <- p2 + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max_count), expand=expansion(mult=c(0,0.15)))

plot_grid(p1, p2, rel_widths=c(1,0.2))
```

[image]

[image]

So, our upper limit fixing works.  You can get really crazy playing around with positioning, etc and the `plot_grid()` function, but I think it works pretty well this way.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Accepted this answer, since it is more generalized and solves more cases; In the end, I decided to use a modified implementation of @YBS ' answer.

Comment: That is definitely simpler, but if you had the case where you needed to use the binning provided by `stat_bin`, then you'd have to resort to something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, this is what you are looking for:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=sample(1:12,50,rep=T))

df2 <- df1 %>%  group_by(x) %>% 
        dplyr::summarise(y=n()) %>% subset(x<11)

df3 <- subset(df1, x>10) %>% dplyr::summarise(y=n()) %>% mutate(x=11)

df <- rbind(df2,df3 )
label <- ifelse((df$x<11),as.character(df$x),">10")
  
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,color=x,fill=x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=df$x,labels=label) 
p
```

and you get the following output:

[image: output]

Please note that sometimes you could have some of the bars missing depending on the sample.

Comment: Thank you @YBS, that is almost the implementation that I planned to do.
A few changed that I made in the end: 
(1) Define >10 as '11' to plot it on a continuous scale. 
(2) Use geom_histogram. 
(3) Rename the label '11' to '>10' with scale_x_continuous.

Obviously, one has to be careful when assigning the value in (1), but it works very well in that particular use-case.